# Stripe multi vendor payment gateway in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I'm building website that is able to sell and buy product inside the website.
Users can post product and buy product from others.
Only remain thing is to integrate with payment gateway.
I'm going to use stripe for payment gateway.
Is it possible to do that with stripe?
Which is the best way to implement this?
The website was built in Laravel 5.4.

Comment: Yes. Laravel already has a full implementation of Stripe for you. It's called Cashier. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing

Comment: Is it possible to send money to seller directly?

Comment: When user buy product from other user, he should pay fee to website owner. Is it possible? Would you please let me know how can I implement this correctly.

Comment: Check my answer for all the links you need.

Comment: Since Cashier does not handle marketplace-like website (aka Stripe Connect). You could use this package for your need: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Stripe for that. Taking advantage of Laravel Cashier. They've already implemented some logic that you can reuse.

Second, you want to pay 'sellers', yes, Stripe does that. Please check Stripe COnnect, which is great for exactly what you are trying to do.
Link: https://stripe.com/connect

This link shows specifically how to charge the user and keep some fees: https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/store-builder

If you follow all the documentation from Cashier, you are good to go. 
Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing

Comment: Is it possible to users to pay affiliate fee regularly every month with standalone account? or is it possible by only managed account?

Comment: You can do both with Stripe. You can do 'Subscriptions' as well as affiliate fees. Remember, Stripe Connect is just a branch of Stripe.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you know any good tutorial for both, please let me know.

Comment: Can I do all things with laravel::Cashier?

Comment: No. But It's easy. You just call API endpoints and parse the response. They list all their endpoints in the second link I gave you.