# composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect this package is incomplete for multi vendor stripe laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier

composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect

```
StripeConnect::transaction($token)
    ->amount(1000, 'usd')
    ->fee(50)
    ->from($customer)
    ->to($vendor)
    ->create();
```

this package is not working. if you know any alternative please let me know. thanks

Comment: Look into it I hope this is helpfull for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406681/stripe-multi-vendor-payment-gateway-in-laravel

Comment: You need to provide more context here. What are you trying to do and what do you expect to happen? Are you following some documented steps/guide? Has this account been connected already? Are you encountering errors or a successful but unexpected result?